# Cant connect to a remote Toad Oracle Database trought instant client

Tags: php

Im tryint to connect remote to a db with this code and i getting this error:

```
<?php
$currDir = getcwd();

putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$currDir/instantclient_21_12");

// Database credentials
$username = 'CTEST';
$password = 'TTEST';
$dsn = 'oci:dbname=bdtest-scan:6589/bdtest_rw.test.com';

// Create a new PDO instance
try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully to Oracle!";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

im trying to connect remote to a Toad Oracle Database but keep getting this error

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\php\ext\oci8_12c (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), C:\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (%1 is not a valid aplicationWin32)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_oci (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (%1 is not a valid aplicationWin32)) in Unknown on line 0

Connection failed: could not find driver
```